# How to retrieve data if you forget the BitLocker key disk?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

In Windows 10, the system partition is encrypted with BitLocker, and the system prompts that you need to insert the key disk to decrypt it.

At present, the key disk and the set key have been lost. And you have logged in to your Windows account, and you are prompted that your key has not been backed up.

In this case, how can we retrieve the data?

Comment: No keys, no data. That's what it's for. If you could bypass that, what would be the point?

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible to recover the data, but it is beyond the capability and resources of most people.

To recover the data you MUST recover key, and if you have lost the key itself, you will need powerful computers and lots of time to attempt to recreate the key. Like, super computers, and even then it'll take lengths of time best measured in lots of years, to recreate the key. Clarification: by lots of years, I mean more years than you have to live, even if you were just born yesterday, AND taking into account likely medical advances.

For the average person, working with the average data, this is just out of the question. This is why there were multiple strong warnings when you applied Bitlocker to the drive about copying and backing up the key.

Comment: Do you have evidence Bitlocker encryption is breakable (in say less then 500 years)? I thought it typically used AES and it was heat-death-of-the-universe type stuff? (ignoring corner cases like relying on faulty ssd encryption  which I know has happened)

Comment: I don't. I was going based on what I'd read a long time ago. Bitlocker uses AES 128bit cyphers. Here's a discussion from out sister site on the subject, though it's about 256bit cyphers: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82389/calculate-time-taken-to-break-aes-key

Comment: The reason the general advice is to use the largest key size possible is due to future computational capacity.  Our ability to do more attempts per second in order to break today’s encryption with something other than a supercomputer is the reason key sizes even increase.  At the end of the day, we are probably save with virtually any reasonable large key size until Quantum computers can be built outside of lab.  AES 128 or AES 256 bit cyphers are virtually in breakable on today’s and probably tomorrow’s x86/IBM/ARM hardware until one of the big players figure out how to build a Quantum proces